# Laravel redirect fails, but direct route works

Tags: laravel-5

If I type `carfreak/owner` into my browser, the expected view comes up. An artisan `route:list` all looks good, and the fact the browser finds it means the route is working.

If I put any of the following, into my controller, I get `route [...] not defined`

- `return redirect()->route('owner');`
- `return redirect()->route('/owner');`
- `return redirect()->route('carfreak/owner');`

What have I missed? 
Laravel documentation says it should work: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

EDIT:

- and `return redirect('owner')` works just fine.

Comment: Share your route that define in route file.

Comment: My routes contains this: `Route::get('/owner', 'DashboardController@ownerDashboard');`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't use `return redirect()->route('/owner');` or `return redirect()->route('carfreak/owner');`

If you redirect to a route then you need to pass **route name** which you set in your routes file by making `'as' => 'routename'` and not use the route adress inside route redirect.